# MVVM Light e.Handled does not keep the state

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am using mvvm light in my wpf application project. For listen the event, i am using `EventToCommand` from MVVM Light library.

The control code looks as follow:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Scannerport"
             Grid.Row="1"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Margin="15,10,40,10"
             MinWidth="100"
             FontSize="40"
             MaxLength="2"
             PreviewTextInput="Scaleport_OnPreviewTextInput"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
             Text="{Binding ScannerPort, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}">
      <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
          <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding OnTextChanged}"
                              PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>


        <rt:RoutedEventTrigger RoutedEvent="{x:Static Validation.ErrorEvent}">
          <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding OnValidationError}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </rt:RoutedEventTrigger>

      </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
```

And in the ViewModel the implemented code:

```
 private void _OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine(e.Handled);
      if (ScalePort != 0 && ScannerPort != 0)
      {
        Disable = true;
        return;
      }

      Disable = false;
    }

    private void _OnValidationError(ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added)
      {
        Disable = true;
        e.Handled = true;
      }
    }
```

As you can see on the second method, I set `e.Handled = true` and then during debugging on first method `e.Handled` is still `false`? 
Why `e.Handled` does not keep the state for next event handler?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think it didn't save it? It's just a different events, and they dont comunicate with each other. So you can't get `e.Handled== true` at `TextChanged` event.

Comment: So it does not pass `e.Handled` to the next handler?

Comment: @zero_coding yes it does not. Validation and PropertyChanged event's not connected directly. WPF check error's and add them to the object binded object (TextBox at this example). And propertychanged event tell you that there some changes. 
Try check [Validation.Errors Attached Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errors(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to check error's on control.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix `e.Handled = true` with different events like what you're doing now.

Listen to the `PreviewTextInput` event and set `e.Handled = true` to stop the `TextChanged` event from being fired again.